# How do you rotate around an object in Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I had already solved this one before, except back then, I was using Ubuntu 14.04 (with a different Desktop).
Now with Ubuntu Studio 16.04, it uses Xfce. Hence, the fixes I had found before are not working with Xfce :(

Everything seems to be working except for rotating around an object. How do you guys do it?

Thanks,

JDL

Comment: Hi, are you sure you're posting this question in the right place?

Comment: try `xfwm4-settings` or `xfce4-settings-editor`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

1. In **Window Manager Tweaks**, in Key used to grab and move windows, changed it to Super.

[image]

2. Then in Blender User Prefs/Input/3D View/3D View (Global)/Rotate View, assign Alt as shown in the image

[image]